# Reasons for cookies not being included with fetch

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I do a fetch with the `credentials` options set to true. My manifest permissions doesn't have `cookies` in it:

```
"permissions": ["storage", "webNavigation", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>", "tabs", "notifications", "downloads"]
```

and my manifest is set for "spanning" on incognito:

```
"incognito": "spanning",
```

For most users, cookies are sent with the fetch, but a few users are reporting issues of not being logged in. When I sent them a debug version to send me html of the pages fetched (i fetch - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/api/key/ ) I am seeing the html of them logged out/on the login form.

Are there any reasons aside from not setting `credentials` that cookies can be missing from the `fetch`? Like should I add `cookies` to permissions?